# Reading mixed ASCII/binary serial data stream -- how to find delimiter?

Tags: python

I am trying to read serial data from a device that outputs in a mix of ASCII and binary, using Python 3.

The message format is: "$PASHR,*msg type*,*binary payload*,*checksum*,\r\n" (minus the quotes)

To make it more interesting, there are several different message types, and they have different payload lengths, so I can't just read X bytes (I can infer the payload length based on the message type). The sequence of a variable number of messages of each type (around 15 in total) is sent every 20 seconds, at 115200 baud.

I haven't been able to read this with serial.readline(), probably because of newlines embedded in the payload.

I think that if I could set the line-end character to the sequence "$PASHR" that would give me a way to frame the messages -- ie, everything between one $PASHR and the next is one message, and the likelihood of seeing the sequence in the binary payload is nil. But I have not been able to make it work either using serial.newline = b'$PASHR' or readuntil(b'$PASHR') -- I still get variable length reads.  I suspect that the serial.timeout setting enters into the solution, but I am not sure how.

Here's the last version I ended up with last night:

```py
     delimiter = b'$PASHR' 
     while True:
            if self.serial.in_waiting:
                message = self.serial.read_until(delimiter)
```

Every method I've tried gives a variable response length, when each record of a give  should be the same length.  Is there a way to set the newline to that multi-character string, or is there a different/better approach I should use?

Thanks!

Comment: I think inter_byte_timeout might help you. If the messages are 20 seconds apart, then you could read until, say, a half second elapses between characters. You could also use read(size=n) if every message is the same length, although I wouldn't rely totally on it as line noise might interfere with transmission, so the timeout would let you catch and discard messages with missing bytes. Looks like 0.1 seconds is the minimum you should use.

Comment: Thanks, Deepstop!  I will check into inter_byte_timeout as it might be a better solution than the regular timeout value.  See below for the solution (before trying that) I found that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. This seems to work with a timeout of 1 second:

```
self.serial.timeout = 1
delimiter = b'$PASHR'
if self.serial.in_waiting:
    message = self.serial.read_until(delimiter)
    if len(message) > 6: # ignore carryover PASHR'
        ***process message***
```

When I looked carefully at the variable length returns, I discovered that the message sequence after the first incomplete cycle was:

```
b'$PASHR' (6 bytes)
b',MPC,*data**checksum*\r\n$PASHR' (108 bytes)
...
b',MPC,*data**checksum*\r\n' (102 bytes)
(delay)
b'$PASHR' (6 bytes)
```

The delimiter from the last message in the sequence is chopped off and output at the beginning of the next sequence. I can deal with that.

I will try Deepstop's idea of the inter_byte timeout as it is probably more elegant than using the raw timeout, and might get around the partial message problem.